# How to send file back to client browser from Java after jQuery.post()

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, http, download

I need help with sending xlsx-file from the server back to the client

This is how it worked BEFORE:

JavaScript (click #export_xls button):

```
export_xls: function(event) {
        window.location = ... + this.workspace.query.id + "/export/xls";
}
```

Java (create xls-file using Apache POI API):

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel" })
@Path("/{queryname}/export/xls/{format}")
public Response getQueryExcelExport(
        @PathParam("queryname") String queryName,
        @PathParam("format") @DefaultValue("flattened") String format){
    // ...
    try {
        byte[] doc = olapQueryService.getExport(queryName,"xls","flat"); // file

        String name = "file.xls";
        return Response.ok(doc, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header(
                "content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename = " + name).header(
                        "content-length",doc.length).build();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Cannot get excel for query (" + queryName + ")",e);
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

And it worked fine, but now i need to send some data from javascript to the java, then java process it and create xlsx
So, i use ajax to send that data (in json format)...

```
export_xls: function(event) {
        var data = this.workspace.query.result.lastresult();
        var url = ...  + this.workspace.query.id + "/testexportxls";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    },
```

...and create my file in java (almost like it was before):

```
@POST
@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel" })
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{queryname}/testexportxls")
public Response setQueryExcelExport(final Object jsonData)
{
    Workbook wb = MyFileBuilder.getFile(jsonData);
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        wb.write(bout);

        byte[] doc = bout.toByteArray();

        String name = "file.xlsx";
        return Response.ok(doc, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header(
                "content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename = " + name).header(
                "content-length",doc.length).build();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        log.error("Error while xlsx-file creating. Exception message: ",e);
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

But i can't get that file now, because of the ajax, i think.

Do you know some quick solution, with minimum code edits?

Unfortunately, I almost know nothing about Response, or some HttpServletResponse and stuff like that =/

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to define a callback function on success, wouldn't that function be able to handle the file?

Seems not, so I'll have a second try: put the JSON in a hidden form input, and POST the form?

Comment: I do not think so. As far as I know, JS itself can't save files on client's computer (security reason). I tried to do something like 

success:function(){ window.location = url; }

But i've got 
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
type Status report
message Method Not Allowed
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).
Apache Tomcat/6.0.24